# How to limit the no of rows to copy in MySQL Workbench Data Migration

Tags: mysql-workbench, migration

I am trying to migrate a huge MS SQL database to a MySQL database using MySQL Workbench.

The source database is too big and i am only interested in 1000 records per table for migration.

Unfortunately i couldn't find a option in MySQL Workbench to limit the no. of Rows to copy from source DB.

Comment: If you manage to restrict all the tables to max of 1000 rows, wouldn't that break foreign key relationships?